# Why does PhpStorm require an instance for a static call to an unspecific type?

Tags: php, phpstorm

### The Problem

I have created a trait with an abstract static function:

```php
trait MyTrait {

    static abstract function x() : mixed;

}
```

and now want to check if any class uses this trait. If yes, lets call the static implementation of x in that class. (`hasTrait` is a function I have written myself)

```php
$type = AnyType::class;
if(hasTrait($type, MyTrait::class) {
    return $type::x(); // <- I expected that this is the right way.
}
```

Now my IDE (PhpStorm) comes up with the error:

> Static member '$type::x()' accessed via instance reference

but type isn't an instance reference... It's a class/type reference.

Weirdly enough, if I now try to instantiate the type:

```php
$type = AnyType::class;
if(hasTrait($type, MyTrait::class) {
    return (new $type)::x();
}
```

it works and PhpStorm doesn't give me any warning at all!

(The first code snippet also runs btw. It's just an error in the editor)

### Description

The description of the inspection is the following:

> Reports references to static methods and fields via a class instance rather than the class itself.
> Even though referring to static members via instance variables is allowed by PHP, this makes the code confusing, as the reader may think that the result of the method depends on the instance.
> The quick-fix replaces the instance variable with the class name.
> Example:

```php
class StaticClass {
    public static function someStaticFunction(): int {
        return 3;
    }
  
}
  
$var = new StaticClass
$var::someStaticFunction();
```

> After the quick-fix is applied:

```php
StaticClass::someStaticFunction()
```

Comment: You've described a phenomenon in PHPStorm, now try to formulate a concrete question which can be answered. Perhaps you should just [file a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)?

Comment: Is this just a bug in PhpStorm or expected behaviour? I'm relatively new to php and know that it has many weird quirks, maybe this is one of them?

Comment: I removed my previous comment because I got deeply confused, sorry about that. Your code has a number of parse errors and we don't know what `hasTrait()` does or whether it's relevant. But if I [try to compose valid PHP code from it](https://3v4l.org/e0nFF#v8.2.11) I don't get that warning at all (PhpStorm/2023.2.2). Not sure what weird quirks you have in mind, but IMHO PHP is way more coherent and intuitive than e.g. JavaScript.

Comment: hasTrait checks if a class uses the passed trait. Its my own implementation.
The inspection is found in: `Editor > Inspections > PHP > General > Class static member accessed via instance`.

And yes, JS is definitely weirder :D

Comment: As far as I can tell `hasTrait($type, MyTrait::class)` would be equivalent to: `$type == MyTrait::class`? Oh yes, Javascript is weird. 

Comment: Nope, its not "`isTrait()`". "`hasTrait()` checks all parent classes for usage recursively.

Comment: OK, yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, alright, apparently it's disabled by default. It's clearly a false positive. The inspection just detects there's a variable on the left side, it is not smart enough to track the variable contents and figure out it's a string with a valid class name.